# Macro Excel: To insert a circle into specific range in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a circle that has a fixed diameter and center. What I need to do now is to insert the circle into the given range. Eg, given 11 boxes of column and 10 boxes of rows to be inserted in excel cell. After entering the given range, the circle will be within the selected range with its fixed center but the boxes would have different measurement for its height and width. My question is how do I insert the circle into any given range (as in 11 x 10 or 9 x 12) with different height and width of the cells?

My code:

```
Sub DrawCircleWithCenter()
Dim cellwidth As Single
Dim cellheight As Single
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim Shp2 As Shape


CellLeft = Selection.Left
CellTop = Selection.Top

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, CellLeft, CellTop, 565 / 2, 565 / 2).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
End With

i = 182
Set Shp2 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(i, CellLeft, CellTop, 20, 20)
Shp2.ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset1
Set rng = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange

Selection.Left = rng.Width / 2 - Selection.Width / 2
Selection.Top = rng.Height / 2 - Selection.Height / 2
Shp2.Left = rng.Width / 2 - Shp2.Width / 2
Shp2.Top = rng.Height / 2 - Shp2.Height / 2


End Sub
```

Comment: What range is your `Selection`?

Comment: As for now, the selection for range is random. When I change the height and width of the cell, the circle would be in different range. Is it possible to make the circle within the range I want? By using Columns x Row.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly this could be what you're after:

```
Sub DrawCircleWithCenter(rng As Range)
  Dim Shp1 As Shape, Shp2 As Shape

  Set Shp1 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height)
  Shp1.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
  With Shp1.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
  End With

  Set Shp2 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(182, rng.Left, rng.Top, 20, 20)
  Shp2.ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset1

  Shp1.Left = rng.Left
  Shp1.Top = rng.Top
  Shp2.Left = rng.Left + rng.Width / 2 - Shp2.Width / 2
  Shp2.Top = rng.Top + rng.Height / 2 - Shp2.Height / 2
End Sub

Sub Test()
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Selection
  DrawCircleWithCenter rng
End Sub
```

You can modify the Test subroutine to supply the range you're after.  In the above case I use the selection that the user has highlighted in the present worksheet to draw the cross and oval centered inside it.  If you choose a square area the oval becomes a circle, with a rectangular area it'll be squashed into an ellipse.  It'll also work if you have varying cell widths and heights in the range you select.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to run the code. It says: Object variable or With block variance not set. What does this mean? Sorry, I'm still new to excel macro.

Comment: What line does it give you that error on?  You have to run the Test subroutine to see it work (ie go to View-> Macros and run Test)

Comment: It works! I run the DrawCircleWithCenter subroutine first, that's why I got an error. Sorry, but I have another question. If I want to make the oval with the fixed height and width (565 / 2, 565 / 2)  would that be possible?

Comment: Yes that's possible but the code has to be changed.

Comment: Which part do I need to change? I tried changing `(msoShapeOval, rng.Left, rng.Top, **rng.Width, rng.Height**)` to `(msoShapeOval, rng.Left, rng.Top, **565/2, 565/2**)`, it doesn't work. The oval is not centered within the highlighted range.

Comment: You can rng.Width and rng.Height both to 565/2 and it should work (ie in 1st addShape line and then in the Shp2.left and Shp2.top lines - ie the latter two would be 565/2/2 or 565/4).  The only thing is that it writes the oval/cross with the proper 'left' and 'top' values which might not be what you want.

Comment: I get what I want. I add `rng.Width / 2 - Shp1.Width / 2 and  + rng.Height / 2 - Shp1.Height / 2` to shp1 and eventually it centered the oval together with the cross. Thanks!